# MongoDB with PHP - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::limit()

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

Am trying to fetch data from MongoDB using PHP.
I have implemented the following code:

```
    $all_items = $collection
        ->find( $where_search, array('_id', 'name', 'email', 'bod', 'mobile') )
        ->limit( $per_page )
        ->skip( $start )
        ->sort( array(
            $Allele => $sort == 'ASC' ? 1 : -1
        ));
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::limit() in /var/www/
```

The used MongoDB version is v4.2, PHP 7.4 and Composer version 2.5.1

I also included the Composer’s autoloader

```
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

and installed the below MongoDB extension and included the

[image]

Comment: You have to follow the doc : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/php-library/current/tutorial/crud/#limit-sort-and-skip-options

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue and this fixed the issue

```
$all_items = $collection
    ->find( $where_search, [
        'projection' => [
             '_id' => 1,
             'name' => 1,
             'email' => 1,
             'bod' => 1,
             'mobile' => 1
         ],
         'limit' => $per_page,
         'skip' => $start,
         'sort' => [
             $Allele => $sort == 'ASC' ? 1 : -1
         ]
    ]);
```